# Objective-C HMAC-256 To Sign HTTP Request - Seeing different results

Tags: objective-c, rest, hmac, sha256

I'm working in Objective-C with a REST API that needs to sign each HTTP request according to this spec (https://web-payments.org/specs/source/http-signatures/).

It all seems straightforward, but I'm having troubles getting what the right "signature" value should be. I'm getting different results in Objective-C VS some of these online sha generators (http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html, http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator).

I put together some sandboxed test code to get this figured out outside of my project.

Here's my test code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

NSString * hmacSHA256(NSString *key, NSString *data) {
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof cHMAC; i++) {
        [result appendFormat:@"%02x", cHMAC[i]];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableString * data = [NSMutableString string];
        [data appendString:@"(request-line) get /\n"];
        [data appendString:@"date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 22:12:37 GMT"];
        NSString * key = @"5a30f5477e2fdea27c5bdef8d5b0b13bfc8c2c77c608169da637a58ac0bff23895b58f8de5ef982a";
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSString * signature = hmacSHA256(key,data);
        NSLog(@"signature: %@",signature);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this test code, I get this as a signature:

```
8315081c226a7b0a77093cf12ec6ce4e112fedff12ddfcfd752c909b58a9ae5e
```

But when I paste in these lines:

```
(request-line) get /
date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 22:12:37 GMT
```

To one of the online generators (http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html, http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator) both of these generators give me the same signature:

```
71b09a1d0b8cde88f2b0c5bb78a06c4539994435e5e47700aa56d2194b9c2f08
```

So how exactly am I supposed to convert the above "unsigned char cHMAC" variable into the proper string?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if that's the actual issue, but isn't the key supposed to be a hex representation of the actual key, rather than an ASCII representation? I.e. you need to decode the hex into bytes?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure that the "(request-line)" isn't meant to be included literally, it just means you should include the request line itself.

Comment: it doesn't matter for my question. what matters is the difference between objc and the online generators. How come I'm not getting the same signatures. The input is the same for each, why the different results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line endings in your text. In reality, your program is generating the correct hash, but you're entering a *different* string into the web tool, which is why you're getting a different result. Here's the text you're feeding to your program:

```
(request-line) get /\ndate: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 22:12:37 GMT
```

And here's what you're feeding to the web tool (assuming you're doing so on Windows, which checks out based on my tests):

```
(request-line) get /\r\ndate: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 22:12:37 GMT
```

Note the '\r\n'. By default, Windows (and, most likely, all web browsers) uses a carriage return AND a line feed character as an EOL sequence. Unix/Linux uses only a line feed, and Mac uses only a carriage return.

If you want to check any other hashes, either add a '\r' into your program for testing, or use a program like Notepad++ where you can control the line endings to create files and then upload them to the second site you listed.

Comment: Actually it's not specific to Windows (same thing on Safari Mac here), it's probably standard for a `textarea` on all platforms.

Comment: yeah that was it. as soon as I changed \n to \r\n it was the same signature.